# How do i enter the password while joining the Linux machine to Active Directory using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, dns, ldap, integration

I am joining Linux machines to windows active directory and i am able to do it successfully using SSSD.

Now I am trying to automate the same process wherein i came across the step where i need to enter a password while joining the domain.

Can someone help in how to enter the password via shell script?

My code is :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

passwd=`cat /domain/domain_join.txt | grep password | awk -F '[=]' '{print$2}'`
 /usr/bin/expect << EOF
 spawn realm join domainname -U username@domainname -v
 expect "Password for username@domainname: \r"
 send "$passwd\r"
EOF
set +x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't actually an LDAP question - it's AD and Kerberos and sshd.

It looks like you've got a user account to join the machine - presumably it has the correct rights. The easiest thing to do is to get a keytab created for that account, and then you can do a `kinit` and call the script in that context

```
kinit principal@EXAMPLE.COM -k -t keytab; joinscript
```

You don't need to define your username in the `realm join` command if you've already done the `kinit`.

Sorry, I can't test this, and it's been a while, but the secret sauce is a keytab for the Windows credential.